# "Firebase - Push Notification not more receiving after some time "

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

We face some problems with Push Notification in our loyalty app. When user install our app first time or reinstall the app, then user receive a push notification in iOS and Android. But after some time (not sure how many days) the user won't receive any push notifications. Means the firebase token is expired and new token is not updated in database. It only works again when the user either reinstall the app or delete the store card and scan QR code again of the specific store. We have a store panel and from there the specific stores can send push notifications to their users. Means the push notification will be send only to user who have the card of this specific store. BTW our app has no registration functionality.

Below are the my code for firebase token:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotificaiton),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

@objc func tokenRefreshNotificaiton(notification: NSNotification) {
        let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()!
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
}
```

Comment: Your code looks quite different from what's in the documentation for [monitoring token refresh events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#monitor-token-refresh).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen below is my code link that is used please check and give your comments.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2febf7ede24089f26fcc0e4150ed9f1120200313075435/d2db0a3c3e08a81fa41593b4f557e3f520200313075518/cc5feb